# No variables to display because there is no current thread

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi I'm new to Java SE development .I am trying to make a guess game for 7 attempts and here is my incomplete(should be with fault). Whenever I'm trying to debug any line the message "net beans no variables to display because there is no current thread"is showing.please give me the solution how can I get rid of this message and what mistake I made in my code and what can be the possible improvement of code.Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ///////////////////part1 random number generation/////////////////////////////////////
        int rnd = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;//so that the position can be started after 0
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Random Number guess Game!\n");
        /////////////////////////part 2 guess it is if that number////////////////////////////

        int number, attempt = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);///////create scanner object
        System.out.print("what did you guess?:");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("you guessed:" + number);

        do {
            if (number > rnd || number < rnd) {
                System.out.println("Guess is incorrect");
            }
            // System.out.println("generated number was:"+rnd);
            System.out.println("generated number was not right");
            System.out.println("try again");
            attempt++;
        } while (number != rnd && attempt < 7);

        if (number == rnd) {
            System.out.println("Guess is correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect 7 attempts");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you still see this message when the program is stopped due to hitting a breakpoint? If the program is currently executing (e.g. not paused by the debugger) you cannot inspect variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have put the breakpoints at the start of the method and you do the line by line debugging using:

**F7 – step into** – executes each source line , if it has method call, and source code is available, pointer moves to that method and executes it. otherwise pointer moves to the next line in the file.

You can see variables while code execution is suspended either through a breakpoint or through you pressing pause while debugging. Then, you may also have to select the program's main thread from the list of threads on the left. At that point, the variables should show up.

Comment: Ok i solved the problem by giving first input and after that debuging started per breakpoints.I did not realized then that if i dont give an input breakspoint wont start to work.THANK YOU FOR WISE INFORMATIONS!

Comment: How do I do the same thing but without F7? I have a couple of matrix loops and can't press F7 180,000 times, but need to know the otehr variables when matrix crashes.